# How to do Image Compression with an Image 10mb to 25mb in size?

Tags: java, image, swing, image-processing, puzzle

I am working on  an image compression technique, I have compressed the image into `.jpg` format and stored it, using Java, I used various functions in java like:

```
obj.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
obj.setCompressionQuality(0.05f);
```

but it only works if the image size is  < 6mb, if it goes beyond that, it throws an exception,

I want to know about some tools(libraries) that are available for image processing.

Thanks.

The Stack trace is given below, its lack of heap memory, [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(DataBufferByte.java:58)
        at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(ComponentSampleM
odel.java:397)
        at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:938)
        at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifi
er.java:1169)
        at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2879)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageRe
ader.java:943)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.jav
a:915)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1282)
        at Compresssion.main(Compresssion.java:13)
```

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace of the thrown exception?

Comment: Try looking at ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer during the debug and see how many bytes it wants to create. Maybe it's simply too large for the memory.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks man

Comment: The java option -Xmx=512m to increase memory is known?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work, no heap space available :(

Comment: What is the maximum heap size you are willing to allocate to the JVM?

Comment: @AlexanderZaldostanov What is your current heap size (when you get the exception)? And what is the amount of memory available for the heap? A normal (RGB/YCbCr encoded) JPEG image will need at least `width` x `height` x `3` bytes of *continuous* free memory. If you don't have this much memory available, it will be very hard to do anything with the image in Java. Also, when you talk about *image size*, do you mean encoded *file size* or actual decoded *image memory size*?

Comment: haraldK I fixed the error bud, Thanks for asking , it was RGB and I compress it to kb's, like 45MB file to KB's, Image format is jpeg